# Ajax Javascript class this undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, class

I'm a beginner with classes in Javascript. 
I'm trying to set up a very simple ajax class but I'm stuck. 
Here's my code:

```
class Ajax {
  constructor() {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  open(method, url, async) {
    this.xhr.open(method, url, async);
    this.xhr.send(null); 
  }

  process() {
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(this.xhr.readyState == 4 && (this.xhr.status == 200 || this.xhr.status == 0)) {
        alert(this.xhr.responseText);
      }   
    }   
  }
}

const ajax = new Ajax();
ajax.open('GET', 'data.php?var1=hello&var2=world', true);
ajax.process();
```

I get this error

`TypeError: this.xhr is undefined`

which refers to the line: `if(this.xhr.readyState == 4 ...`

Can someone explain what's the pb here and how to solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupllicate (probably several times over), but can't find an appropriate one. Short answer is it's to do with how `this` in JS works, and inside the callback to `onreadystatechange` its no longer referring to the class. There are a number of fixes, but the easiest is to use an arrow function for the callback.

Comment: Try to `console.log` this in `onreadystatechange` function. I bet that it is not your class. You often need to preserve the value of this in event handlers

Comment: @nickzoum no, the "new" `this` reference will be to the global object [EDIT: actually, you might be right. Depends on exactly how the `onreadystatechange` gets called internally. I must admit I rarely use `XMLHttpRequest` directly, I either use `$.ajax` if using jQuery, or these days I try to use `fetch`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try following code.

With Reference.

```
class Ajax {
  constructor() {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  open(method, url, async) {
    this.xhr.open(method, url, async);
    this.xhr.send(null); 
  }

  process() {
    const xhrRef = this.xhr; // storing reference.

    xhrRef.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhrRef.readyState == 4 && (xhrRef.status == 200 || xhrRef.status == 0)) {
        alert(xhrRef.responseText);
      }   
    }   
  }
}

const ajax = new Ajax();
ajax.open('GET', 'data.php?var1=hello&var2=world', true);
ajax.process();
```

Without Reference

```
class Ajax {
  constructor() {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  open(method, url, async) {
    this.xhr.open(method, url, async);
    this.xhr.send(null); 
  }

  process() {
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(this.readyState == 4 && (this.status == 200 || this.status == 0)) {
        alert(this.responseText);
      }   
    }   
  }
}

const ajax = new Ajax();
ajax.open('GET', 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees', true);
ajax.process();
```

Comment: What is difference between taking reference and without reference? Could you please explain it?

Comment: We can do it both way.

Comment: Can you please provide example of this by taking without reference?